# position div related to another div with responsive arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

am trying to make responsive menu related to div as you see in my jsfiddle Demo link,
my problem with arrow and menu position , i need to add class if menu closest to right border of container or even to left border or top border or bottom border , i mean change position of menu and  change arrow position and also to make menu not ever come out of container..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhtquuhs/1/)

This Is My Code :

```
var popupid,gid = 0;
$(".box").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

        placeholder();

    var self = $(this),
            pos = self.position(),
            selftop = pos.top,
            selfleft = pos.left,
            width = self.outerWidth(),
            popup_Options = self.find(".popup");

        popupid = 'placeholder-' + gid++;
        popup_Options
            .attr('placeholder', popupid)
            .before('<div class="placeholder ' + popupid + '"></div>') 
            .appendTo('.Container');   

            popup_Options.css({
                position: "absolute",
                top: selftop + "px",
                left: (selfleft + width)  + 20 +"px"
            }).show();

    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').on('click',function(e)
{
    placeholder();
});

function placeholder()
{
            // Move back out of container
        $('div[placeholder="'+popupid+'"]')
            .appendTo('.placeholder.' + popupid)  
            .unwrap()                               
            .removeAttr('placeholder')
            .hide(); // Unset placeholder data

}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve.  Can you explain more clearly?  What is this "arrow" that you are talking about?

Comment: arrow, i mean tooltip arrow !! as here http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Ah - now I understand :)